# How to design readiness and livness probe for Angular application

Tags: angular, apache, kubernetes, readinessprobe, livenessprobe

I have an angular application which is deployed on apache container running on Kubernetes. I wanted to setup liveness and readiness probe for pods but I am out of ideas .Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you build the angular container image, what is inside?

Comment: ng build --prod command compiles the Angular code into a folder which is copied into apache web server which hosts the files.

Comment: I have followed Dockerfile from here ..instead of nginx used apache
https://www.indellient.com/blog/how-to-dockerize-an-angular-application-with-nginx

Comment: Could you share your Deployment yaml file? It will be easier to help you if we will see your configuration

Answer (score 3):

Base on the link you provided, you can use the following as a start:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
...
spec:
  ...
  containers:
  - name: ...
    ...
    livenessProbe:
      tcpSocket:
        port: 80               # <-- live when your web server is running
      initialDelaySeconds: 5   # <-- wait 5s before starting to probe
      periodSeconds: 20        # <-- do this probe every 20 seconds
    readinessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /                # <-- ready to accept connection when your home page is serving
        port: 80
      initialDelaySeconds: 15
      periodSeconds: 10
      failureThreshold: 3      # <-- must not fail > 3 probes
```

Comment: Can I setup a angular route and check the liveness probe with httpinterceptor mocking response , not sure if Angular routes can be directly hit through k8s